# VBA Acceptable File Types for Submission

Tags: excel, vba, forms, file

I have a form that that will browse my device for a file to be submitted. I can set the file type to just one type, and in this case only excel files. What I would like to set are 2 files types that I can select from my device. So excel files and word documents.

```
Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click()

    Dim result As Variant

    result = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsm), *xlsm")

    If result <> False Then
        filetextbox.Text = result
    End If

End Sub
```

The code above is what I have that will allow me to select only excel files for submission, works fine.

```
result = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsm), *xlsm")
result = Application.GetOpenFilename("Microsoft Word Document(*.docx), *.docx")
```

I tried this, it kind of works however when I browse my device, the browse window will allow me to only select excel files, and if I close out, another browse window will appear that will only allow me to select word documents. I would like for one browse window that will allow me select both file types, without another window appearing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can just combine them into a custom filter:

```
Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click()

Dim result As Variant
Dim filter As String

filter = "Word and Excel Files (*.doc;*.docx;*.xls;*.xlsx),*.doc;*.docx;*.xls;*.xlsx"

result = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter)

If result <> False Then
    filetextbox.Text = result
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a variation on the answer from @FlexYourData. Instead of listing both Word *and* Excel files at the same time you can have the choice of listing Word *or* Excel files. Take your pick.

```
filter = "Word Files(*.doc;*.docx),*.doc;*.docx, Excel Files(*.xls;*.xlsx), *.xls;*.xlsx"
```

Answer (score 0):

### Browse Files Using GetOpenFileName

**Main**

```
Private Sub BtnBrowse_Click()

    Dim FileFilterString As String: FileFilterString = GetFileFilterString
    If Len(FileFilterString) > 255 Then Exit Sub
     
    Dim Result As Variant:
    Result = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilterString)
    
    If VarType(Result) = vbBoolean Then
        MsgBox "Canceled by user.", vbExclamation
        'FileTextBox.Text = ""
    Else
        MsgBox Result
        'FileTextBox.Text = Result
    End If

End Sub
```

**Help**

```
Function GetFileFilterString() As String
        
    ' Define constants.
    
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Get File Filter String" ' for the MsgBoxes
    ' If you keep this one as 'True' (I would), in the calling procedure,
    ' you can simply use e.g. 'If Len(FileFilterString) > 255 Then Exit Sub'.
    Const SHOW_MESSAGE_TOO_MANY_CHARACTERS As Boolean = True
    ' These two might become useful when building the strings
    ' so you can check what you got so far since you can run this
    ' function from the VBE because it has no parameters.
    Const SHOW_MESSAGE_RESULT As Boolean = False
    Const DEBUG_PRINT_RESULT As Boolean = False
    
    ' Declare variables for building the string.
    Dim ffString As String, ffWild As String, Result As String
    
    ' Copy Area
    
    ' Copy these lines as many times as necessary (or more) and build each.
    ' Keep these ones unbuilt here!
    ' Any unbuilt ones won't affect the result!
    ffString = ""
    ffWild = ""
    Result = Result & "," & ffString & "," & ffWild ' Leave as-is!
    
    ' Paste (Build) Area
    
    ffString = "Excel and Word Files (*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*;*.doc*;*.dot*)"
    ffWild = "*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*;*.doc*;*.dot*"
    Result = Result & "," & ffString & "," & ffWild ' Leave as-is!
    
    ffString = "Excel Files (*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*)"
    ffWild = "*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*"
    Result = Result & "," & ffString & "," & ffWild ' Leave as-is!
    
    ffString = "Word Files (*.doc*;*.dot*)"
    ffWild = "*.doc*;*.dot*"
    Result = Result & "," & ffString & "," & ffWild ' Leave as-is!
    
    ' Remove this one after you see what it causes and you're done playing.
    ffString = "WhatEver files (just to push over the 255 Characters limit)"
    ffWild = "12345678.*"
    Result = Result & "," & ffString & "," & ffWild ' Leave as-is!
    
    ffString = ""
    ffWild = ""
    Result = Result & "," & ffString & "," & ffWild ' Leave as-is!

    ' Finishing Touches

    ' Remove double commas.
    Do While InStr(Result, ",,") > 0: Result = Replace(Result, ",,", ""): Loop
    ' Remove leading and trailing commas.
    If Left(Result, 1) = "," Then Result = Right(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
    If Right(Result, 1) = "," Then Result = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
    
    ' Validation (255 Characters Limit)
    
    Dim LenResult As Long: LenResult = Len(Result)
    Dim LenDiff As Long: LenDiff = LenResult - 255
    Dim JoinedResult As String: JoinedResult = Join(Split(Result, ","), vbLf)
    If LenDiff > 0 Then
        If SHOW_MESSAGE_TOO_MANY_CHARACTERS Then
            MsgBox "The file filter string " & vbLf & vbLf & JoinedResult _
                & vbLf & vbLf & "is by " & LenDiff & " character" _
                & IIf(LenDiff = 1, "", "s") & " too long.", _
                vbCritical, PROC_TITLE
        End If
    End If
    If SHOW_MESSAGE_RESULT Then
        MsgBox "The file filter string " & vbLf & vbLf & JoinedResult _
            & vbLf & vbLf & "is " & LenResult & " character" _
            & IIf(LenDiff = 1, "", "s") & " long.", _
            vbInformation, PROC_TITLE
    End If
    If DEBUG_PRINT_RESULT Then
        Debug.Print JoinedResult
    End If
    
    ' Result
    
    GetFileFilterString = Result
    
End Function
```

**Debug Print Results**

```
Excel and Word Files (*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*;*.doc*;*.dot*)
*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*;*.doc*;*.dot*
Excel Files (*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*)
*.xl*;*.xls*;*.xlt*
Word Files (*.doc*;*.dot*)
*.doc*;*.dot*
WhatEver files (just to push over the 255 Characters limit)
12345678.*
```